# Trouble adding two mysql columns and returning total

Tags: php, mysql

I am attempting to add mysql columns and then return the total of the columns to a php page. I got the code to work but it is not returning the value:

```
<?
$pointresults2 = $dbh->prepare("SELECT sum(features + contributions + likes 
)   
AS total FROM points WHERE (ID = :user_ID)");
$pointresults->bindParam(':user_ID', $user_ID, PDO::PARAM_INT); 
$pointresults2->execute();
$pointrow2 = $pointresults2->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
?>

<h3><b>Points TEST: <?php echo $pointrow2[0]['total'] ?></b></h3>
```

Comment: `features,contributions,likes`: These are _columns_ in the table? You should not be binding them with `bindParam()` if they are. You would only be binding `:user_ID` (not using `$user_ID`).  Please clarify a little what your table's structure is and what values are actually _input_ to the query.

Comment: What is your error? Show it.

Comment: Why do you say `SELECT select *`...?

Comment: Sorry for delay. Yes, these are columns is a table called points that I want to add together. So if people contribute content, they get 3 points added to contributions. But what I am trying to do now is get a total of all the different kinds of points (columns) added together and returned as a total sum of all points across all categories/columsn

Comment: the error code is: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select *,(features + contributions + likes ) AS total FROM 'points' WHERE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `features`, `contributions`, `likes` in your condition. Also you are giving wrong name as parameter `user_ID`.

```
<?php
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT sum(features + contributions + likes) AS total FROM points WHERE (ID = :user_ID)");
$stmt->bindParam(':user_ID', $user_ID, PDO::PARAM_INT); 
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

echo '<h3>'. $user_ID .' have '. $row['total'] .' Points.</h3>';
?>
```

Comment: I don't think this is the OP's intent at all.  If the values of those 3 columns were already known, there'd be no need to add them up in the query.

Comment: Yes, I want to hear his response or maybe error, because I saw `$features`, `$contribution`, and `$likes`

Comment: Sorry for delay. Yes, these are columns is a table called points that I want to add together. So if people contribute content, they get 3 points added to contributions. But what I am trying to do now is get a total of all the different kinds of points (columns) added together and returned as a total sum of all points across all categories/columns

Comment: I got it half right...see amended post. No more errors. But it is not returning a value. The echo statement is incorrect....

Comment: @jaw : I do rename some of your variable for easy reading. It should works now.

Comment: Great job Colour Dalnet!!! What did you change in the select statement to make it work???

Comment: `$pointresults2` should be `$pointresults` that's all. Do not create duplicate question !!!